# Working with sound card in Linux. Understanding first example (Why not UB?)

Tags: c, linux, undefined-behavior, alsa

I'm reading `ALSA` [***tutorial***](http://alsamodular.sourceforge.net/alsa_programming_howto.html) and faced some misunderstanding. In the `2. Basic PCM audio` section there is a code example:

```
snd_pcm_t *pcm_handle;          //uninitialized
snd_pcm_stream_t stream = SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK;
snd_pcm_hw_params_t *hwparams;
char *pcm_name;
pcm_name = strdup("plughw:0,0");
snd_pcm_hw_params_alloca(&hwparams); //macro, must be ok
if (snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, pcm_name, stream, 0) < 0) { // <--- !!HERE!!
  fprintf(stderr, "Error opening PCM device %s\n", pcm_name);
  return(-1);
}
```

I don't understand why isn't it UB. We pass unitialized `&pcm_handle` to the `snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, pcm_name, stream, 0)` which should be UB. Why is it ok?

Comment: It is an "out parameter"

Comment: @Raman but if a pointer is unitialized and used it is UB, isn't it?

Comment: No, why using an uninitialised pointer would be undefined behavior? It will be assigned some value inside `snd_pcm_open`. It is not being dereferenced before getting initialised.

Comment: Have you ever seen the `Stuff stuff; init_stuff(&stuff);` idiom?

Comment: @n.m. Already read about it, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not "using an uninitialized pointer". You're taking its address for something else to store a value to it. The pointer is a red herring. This is no different from `int x; scanf("%d", &x);`

Comment: Understood. As far as I got the `hwparams` has automatic storage duration and is already initialized to undeterminated value by the I'm using address of operation [N1570, Section 6.7.9](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf). Is that correct?